# Открыта сессия, юзер загружает файл, это файл надо прицепить в id юзера

Tags: php, mysql

Как узнать id пользователя по сессии?
`$_SESSION['ник пользователя']` можно к нику привязать, но надо к id.

Вот еще, попробoвал так id вытащить

```
$sessionuser = $_SESSION['sender'];

$userid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE name='$sessionuser'");
```

заношу в базу, сессия правильно вбивается, то есть эта переменная `$sessionuser`, все ок, а переменная `$userid` должна id вбивать в базу, но там пишет на все запросы

> Resource id #2

Comment: Читай [документацию][1] и там-же смотри примеры как правильно работать с `mysql_query()`


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @eicto, суть не в том что `mysql_query()` - устаревшая функция. И в mysqli и в pdo выдача получается по тому-же принципу. Важно чтобы человек понял как работать с ресурсом для получения результата.

Answer (score 1):

Ну так все правильно... чтоб получить данные используй [`mysql_result()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-result.php) или [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) или [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

А фунция [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) должна возвращать Resource!